# VBA Finding Max value, without using MAX function and printing corresponding cell

Tags: vba, excel, function, max

I think I need to do a loop here but I'm not quite sure how exactly to write out the syntax as I'm used to just using the max function.

The function I need to create takes in two arrays; the first array has the numeric values while the second array has strings. The function is supposed to find the value in the first array that is the largest and return the corresponding string from the second array.

I'm not sure exactly how to construct my loop. I'm thinking I need to use some form of conditional statements.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Function FindMax(valueArray() As Integer, nameArray() As String) As String
Dim i As Long, y As Long
y = valueArray(0) 'change to 1 if using a different array structure
FindMax = nameArray(0) 'change to 1 if using a different array structure
For i = LBound(valueArray, 1) To UBound(valueArray, 1)
    If valueArray(i) > y Then
        y = valueArray(i)
        FindMax = nameArray(i)
    End If
Next i
Debug.Print ; y
Debug.Print ; FindMax
```

End Function

Comment: Does this need to be done in VBA or would a single worksheet function suffice?  Better than a loop would be a `Max`/`Match`/`Index` (either on the worksheet or with VBA using `Application.WorksheetFunction`.  Are you familiar with `Index/Match` lookups?

Comment: I've been using the developer tab in excel and writing the code in the module. My goal is to get the module running as an excel formula. That being said, I can't use any functions as that is a requirement for this exercise.

Comment: Good stuff... I started with VBA by recording macros while I "did stuff in Excel", then I'd analyze the [messy] code it produced, line by line, with the help of my best friends: search engines & forums. (Unfortunately that was long before Stack Overflow or even Google were around...)

Comment: my condolences @ashleedawg LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function FindMax(valueArray() As Integer, nameArray() As String) As String
    dim i as long, y as long    
    y = valueArray(0) 'change to 1 if using a different array structure
    FindMax = nameArray(0) 'change to 1 if using a different array structure
    for i = lbound(valueArray,1) to ubound(valueArray,1)
        if valueArray(i) > y then
            y = valueArray(i)
            FindMax = nameArray(i)
        end if 
    next i 
End Function
```

[image]

Pay attention to the bottom half of the code. See where is say :

```
this=FindMax(arr,arr2)
```

?

That is how you call a function. Obviously you'll need two arrays to pass to this function. I suggest googling "Functions vba" and do some light reading.

Comment: @BradleyC I tested this just now and works fine for me. Did you try a debug.print to make sure the correct value was being returned?

Comment: Yes I just added that to the code, and it still returns no value in excel. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: @BradleyC Try posting evrything you have in code and then I can pinpoint your issue. I cant really troubleshoot for you since you really didnt provide anything to begin with

Comment: Posted in the original question.

Comment: @BradleyC you are not saying how you are calling the function - am I incorrect in assuming that you do not know how to call functions yet? You mentioned previously thi was an assignment so maybe you are like *really* new at this and need things explained

Answer (score 2):

Here's a worksheet formula that gets the job done quick & easy:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$10,MATCH(MAX($B$3:$B$10),$B$3:$B$10))
```

---

[image: screenshot]

**If your:**

- Numbers of which to find the **Maximum** are in cells `B3:B10`, and,
- Strings that you want to return are in cells `C3:C10`

...then the **Maximum** can be found with:

*{MyMax}* `=MAX($B$3:$B$10)`

...and the "**Position #**` of *{MyMax}* can be found with:

*{Pos#}* `=MATCH(` *{MyMax}* `,$B$3:$B$10)`

...and the corresponding string can be found with:

`=INDEX($C$3:$C$10,` *{Pos#}* `)`

...so if we put it all together, we get:

`=INDEX($C$3:$C$10,MATCH(MAX($B$3:$B$10),$B$3:$B$10))`

---